# Install Debian Linux

Tags: debian

Загрузил образ **ISO** Debian Linux'а, создал загрузочную флешку, и при загрузки с этой флешки загружается grub...

Сейчас установлена ОС Linux Ubuntu 20.04...

Почему так происходит ? Как можно исправить это ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Как записывал флешку?

Comment: С помошью утилиты dd

Comment: Лучше поставь на флешку Ventoy. А дальше просто. Копируешь на флешку iso образ. Грузишься с флешки, появляется окно выбора Ventoy, выбираешь там нужный iso и загружаешь его.